# Splitting a string on space except for single space

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I was splitting a string on white spaces using the following

```
myString.split("\\s+");
```

How do i provide exception for single space. i.e split on space except for single space

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
myString.split("\\s{2,}");
```

or like this,

```
myString.split(" \\s+"); // notice the blank at the beginning.
```

It depends on what you really want, which is not clear by reading the question.

You can check the quantifier syntax in the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

Comment: @dystroy how is this opposite?

Comment: Won't this also not split on a single `tab`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that wasn't part of the question by OP! Right?

Comment: or regex `"\\s\\s+"` or even simpler `"  +"`

Comment: @zEro He is currently splitting on all and any whitespace and seemed to want to exclude only single space from that. Apparently I over-read the question, since John seems happy :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Oh!You're right! I'm misinterpreting everything today!

Comment: @Bohemian `" +"` will also match one space

Comment: None of your solutions exclude a single space and nothing else, and the second solution is even further away from that. That's literally what OP asked; also, it's at least somewhat of a challenge :)

Comment: @fge you can't see it, but there were *two* spaces in there, ie `"<space><space>+"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pattern like

```
myString.split("\\s\\s+");
```

This only matches if a whitespace character is followed by further whitespace charactes.

Please note that a whitespace character is more than a simple blank.

Comment: How is this different from `myString.split("\\s{2,}");` ?

Comment: The result is the same, it's only another way to write it. It will perhaps show the intention of the original poster more exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
"Your String".split("\\s{2,}");
```

will do the job.

For example:

```
String str = "I am  a  String";
String []strArr = str.split("\\s{2,}");
```

This will return an array with length 3.

The following would be the output.

```
strArr[0] = "I am"
strArr[1] = "a"
strArr[2] = "String"
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally want to exclude a single *space*, as opposed to other types of whitespace, then you'll need the following:

```
s.split("\\s{2,}|[\\s&&[^ ]]")
```

This constructs a character class by subtracting the space from the `\s` built-in character class.